# Why is Git Bash called bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

Why is Git Bash called "bash"? Is there really that much connection between the git shell and the unix shell? For instance, when Git Bash is being used on Windows I don't believe many Unix commands are understood. Wouldn't it be better named "Git Shell" and not "Git Bash"? Bash should remain a specific reference to the Unix "Bourne-again shell". Can someone explain what I might be missing?

Update: A year ago, the version of Git I was using incorporated something called Git Bash. Nowadays, if I download "github for windows" from Github, I get an icon for a GUI to talk directly with Github and an icon called "Git Shell", not "Git Bash", as you see in the image below. So I just realized that someone might have felt the same way as me before I felt that way.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this question is "primarily opinion-based". Git Bash is called bash because it's bash. (See my answer.)

Comment: I just installed the latest Git for Windows on my Windows 7 laptop. It installs "Git GUI" and "Git Bash", so there's been no change. GitHub for Windows is a different application, designed to work with http://github.com -- and it's "Git Shell" program is Windows PowerShell, not Bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Git Bash` *is* the GNU bash shell. Try typing `echo $BASH_VERSION` at the prompt.

Like any shell, it has some built-in commands (all of which should be available); other commands are executables you can invoke from the shell. If some of those commands happen to be missing, that's not an attribute of the shell; those commands just don't happen to be installed on your system.

What you're missing is that most of the command you invoke at a shell prompt are not part of the shell.

Comment: Keith - see my update above, feel free to comment or correct, thanks

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows system at the moment, but later I'll try installing the latest Git for Windows on my laptop. Unless there's been a substantial change, I expect that the "Git Shell" is still really bash (which you can confirm by typing `echo $BASH_VERSION` at the prompt). My guess is that the icon name was motivated by the idea that Windows users are more likely to know (and care) what a "shell" is than what "Bash" is.